# postman's newman json reporter console not showing summary

Tags: postman

I'm running newman on the command line with the following arguments:

newman run #{collection} -g #{globals} -r json --reporter-json-export #{output_file}

The problem is that I don't see the summary in the output json file. If I run newman with the cli or html reporters, I do indeed see the summary, but text/html is hard to parse. I guess I'm doing something wrong because I see a sample on github which is json with summary: https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/blob/develop/examples/reports/html-reporter-template-data.json

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running an old version of Postman. Did in an npm install newman which installed the latest version and it's all working.